# Can you create a button to update status inside email alert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, email, button, alerts

I have a rails app that allows people to offer a donation to a non-profit. The recipient of the offer receives an email alerting them of the offer.  The offer also gets recorded in the database with a default status of pending but on the site they can change the status to accepted or rejected.  Right now the recipient has to go to the website and login to change the offer status. I want to know if it's possible to allow them to change the status of the offer from within the email alert they receive? And if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Controller with a function lets say **status**

```
def status
  ...
end
```

And then catch it with a **GET**

```
website.com/newcontrollers/status/?id=x&uid=xxx&token=
```

The other way could be to add a new function in the **Offers Controller** and exclude it in the authentication.

Comment: What will happen, if mailer-spider will check that link? it's not safe, right?

Comment: I have never heard of mailer-spiders, but also all confirmation emails for start-ups use that kind of function.

Comment: Thanks @robzdc, you've put me on the right path. Which was the intent of the question.  Right now I'm figuring out how to pass the authenticity token through the controller.  As a work around in development I've used **skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create, :update]** but I have a feeling this isn't good for security. Or actually that's probably why you recommend a **GET** request so I don't have to deal with that at all.

Comment: You could add a **token** column in Offer Model and then create a unique Token with **SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64**, then send that in the **GET**